# Run rest of batch commands after vagrant starts

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, vagrant

1) Hello I want to make a script to run a script to start vagrant from different directory and when i log in to it i want to start few commands inside vagrant, is it possible?

script.bat

```
call ng build
call node copy.js
cd \b\
vagrant up
vagrant ssh
cd /
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
java -jar /opt/app/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

For now it stops after I log in to vagrant using vagrant ssh.
Additionally:
2) Also do you know a command that I could use to stay in my directory after I exit from vagrant. I originally run this script from directory C:/a and I want to run these commands inside C:/b folder and want to stay inside C:/a after exiting.
I tried pushd and popd but with no effect.

3) Also do is it possible to not run vagrant up when I do exit from vagrant but it is still up?

Comment: Use backslashes for paths in Windows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

1. do [vagrant shell provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html) that can be run always so add something like in your Vagrantfile

   ```
     config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, run: "always", inline: <<-SHELL
       sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start
       sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
       java -jar /opt/app/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
     SHELL
   ```

so that will run those commands each time you run `vagrant up`

2. run the commands from `vagrant ssh` from the script.bat file, something like

   ```
   call ng build
   call node copy.js
   cd \b\
   vagrant up
   vagrant ssh -c "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start"
   vagrant ssh -c "sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start"
   vagrant ssh -c "java -jar /opt/app/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
   ```

To asnwer 2nd point

> Also do you know a command that I could use to stay in my directory after I exit from vagrant. I originally run this script from directory C:/a and I want to run these commands inside C:/b folder and want to stay inside C:/a after exiting

vagrant will return to the current directory it was running.

Lets say you run from c:/a your script, inside your script you're running to c:/b, when you exit from vagrant, it will return from c:/b. If you want to exit and return to c:/a, make sure to initiate a `cd c:/a` before executing vagrant command

> 3) Also do is it possible to not run vagrant up when I do exit from vagrant but it is still up?

Its not clear - `vagrant up` means you boot a VM and it is running - after this you can ssh to get inside the VM but you exit the VM at this point, the VM is still up and running until you run vagrant halt.

You might have some confusion between how vagrant is running and how it runs within your script. Make sure you get familiar to the way vagrant is running and then after you can script it.

Comment: Thanks for your satisfying answer and time you took to write more than just go to ... like some other do, will try both ways right away and mark as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `pushd` and `popd`
Stores the current directory for use by the POPD command, then
changes to the specified directory.

PUSHD [path | ..]

path        Specifies the directory to make the current directory.

If Command Extensions are enabled the PUSHD command accepts
network paths in addition to the normal drive letter and path.
If a network path is specified, PUSHD will create a temporary
drive letter that points to that specified network resource and
then change the current drive and directory, using the newly
defined drive letter.  Temporary drive letters are allocated from
Z: on down, using the first unused drive letter found.

Comment: This is not what the question is about.